# Can anyone explain, why there are coefficients 2 in the equation for rate of change [A]?

Tags: kinetics, rate-equation

> The reaction mechanism for the decomposition of $\ce{A2}$ is thought to be:
>
> \begin{align}
> \ce{A2 &<=>[$k_1$][$k_1'$] A + A} & &\text{ (fast)} \\[0.2cm]
> \ce{A + B &<=>[$k_2$] P} & &\text{ (slow)}
> \end{align}
>
> The rate of formation of intermediate $\ce{A}$ is given by:
>
> \begin{align}
> \frac{\mathrm{d}[\ce{A}]}{\mathrm{d}t} = \color{red}{2} k_1[\ce{A2}] - \color{red}{2}k_1'[\ce{A}]^2 - k_2[\ce{A}][\ce{B}] \approx 0
> \end{align}

In the equation above, why is the coefficient of $2$ present for both the forward and reverse reactions (highlighted in red)?

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry! A screenshot or picture of an exercise is not searchable. Please consider rewriting it, so that it can be of help for future visitors.

Comment: ([])/=_ [ ]−_(−) []^−_ [][] for reaction mechanism 1. _→+         _ and 2.  +→_        _(−)
and 3. +→         _

Comment: It would be really great if you could [edit] your question. On Chemistry mathematical and chemical expressions can be formatted using MathJax (and LaTeX Syntax).  If you want to know more, please have a look [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) and [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/4945).

Comment: I did it for you this time, but please do take a look at the guide which Martin linked.

Comment: Thank you, this is my first question, so I leran.

Comment: There is an answer to a v. similar question here https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/151970/steady-state-approach-how-to-find-rate-equation-for-intermediate/151989#151989

Answer (score 7):

$$\ce{A_n ->[$k$] nA}$$

For the reaction given above, rate of formation of $\ce{A}$ is defined as:

$$\frac{1}{n}\frac{\mathrm d\ce{[A]}}{\mathrm dt} = k\ce{[A_n]}$$

In this case, we have three different reactions that involve A. They are:

\begin{align}
\ce{A_n &->[$k_1$] nA} \tag{1}\label{1}\\
\ce{nA &->[$k_1'$] A_n} \tag{2}\label{2}\\
\ce{A + B &->[$k_2$] P} \tag{3}\label{3}\\
\end{align}

Writing the rate equations for $\eqref{1}$, $\eqref{2}$, $\eqref{3}$ and summing them up to get total rate, we get:

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{n}\frac{\mathrm d\ce{[A]1}}{\mathrm dt} &= k_1\ce{[A_n]} \tag{4}\label{4}\\
-\frac{1}{n}\frac{\mathrm d\ce{[A]2}}{\mathrm dt} &= k'_1 [\ce{A}]^n\tag{5}\label{5}\\
-\frac{\mathrm d\ce{[A]3}}{\mathrm dt} &= k_2\ce{[A][B]} \tag{6}\label{6}\\
\frac{\mathrm d\ce{[A]_\mathrm{tot}}}{\mathrm dt} &= \frac{\mathrm d\ce{[A]1}}{\mathrm dt} + \frac{\mathrm d\ce{[A]2}}{\mathrm dt}+\frac{\mathrm d\ce{[A]3}}{\mathrm dt} \tag{7}\label{7} \\  
\end{align}

Substituting values from $\eqref{4}$, $\eqref{5}$, $\eqref{6}$ into $\eqref{7}$, we get:

$$\frac{\mathrm d\ce{[A]_\mathrm{tot}}}{\mathrm dt} = \color{red}{n}k_1\ce{[A_n]} - \color{red}{n}k'_1\ce{[A]^n} - k_2\ce{[A][B]} $$

Here, $n = 2$, therefore

$$\frac{\mathrm d\ce{[A]_\mathrm{tot}}}{\mathrm dt} = \color{red}{2}k_1\ce{[A_n]} - \color{red}{2}k'_1\ce{[A]^2} - k_2\ce{[A][B]} $$

Comment: Thank you very much! But I still a little be confused, shouldn't it be [A] to the power of n in the equation (5)? That gives quadratic equation for the intermediate for the given mechanism..

Comment: I tried this way to solve next problem. The suggested reaction mechanism is the same, but first reaction is switched. In the textbook,(which is Atkins PhysChem), coefficient 2 appears only for forward reaction. Is it mistake or the I need to use different approach?

Comment: @Tara Please use the answer field only for actual answers. If you are new to the site, I suggest you take the [tour] and learn more about it. I have converted your answer to a comment here; if you have more follow up questions, it might be better to ask again and link here for context, see also [ask].